# Metodo "onclick" no funciona en archivos agregados con "<?php require ?>

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Bueno mi problema es el siguiente, tengo una web de una inmobiliaria.
Tiene un Sidebar a la derecha con botones para entrar en las diferentes secciones,
la parte "principal" que es la que esta a la izquierda y ocupa el 70% de la pantalla es donde se hace un Display de todas las casas a la venta, llamadas mediante el método `onclick=""` que a su vez ejecuta una funcion **JQuery+AJAX**
que es la siguiente:

```
function cargarDoc(url) {
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    dataType: "text",
    success : function (data) {
        $(".1").html(data);
    }
});}
```

Y el codigo html es el siguinte:

```
<aside>
        <div class="widget">
            <p class="s" href="" onclick="cargarDoc('aptoarriendo.php');cargarDoc2('aptoventa.php');"><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>Apartamentos</p>
            <p class="s" href="" onclick="cargarDoc('casaarriendo.php');cargarDoc2('casaventa.php');"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Casas</p>
            <p class="s" href="" onclick="cargarDoc3('calle11con12.html')"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>LOL</p>
        </div>
    </aside>
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, la lista de casas es agregada exitosamente en la sección principal como ven en la siguient imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, al hacer **Hover** en una casa, se muestra un botón que dice "Informacion" y la idea es que al hacer click, el metodo `onclick=""` re actualice esa sección principal, con otro archivo html que muestre información detallada de la casa, pero, por mucho que agrego el `onclick=""` con su respectiva función, no pasa absolutamente nada al hacer click.
Para probar, puse también un botón "LOL" el cual por alguna razón, si actualiza la sección como debería hacer el botón de la imagen.
Mi teoría es que en el Sidebar funciona por ser una sección aparte a la que va a ser actualizada, y en la propia sección no funciona porque no se pude actualizar a si misma. A ver si alguien da en el clavo.

Muchisimas gracias de antemano y un saludo!.

Answer (score 1):

La razón es porque los escuchadores de eventos se asocian cuando el documento se carga en la etapa del parseo del documento. Entonces, cuando agregas el HTML de manera dinámica, se necesita de alguna manera volver a *parsear* los scripts para que se asocien correctamente los eventos al HTML añadido recientamente.

Lo que puedes hacer es:

1. Por cada template tener una etiqueta `script`.
2. Una vez añadido el HTML re-evaluar los scripts mediante `eval`.
3. Usar el patrón de carga dinámica de scripts.

En mi opinión, la mejor forma es la opción dos y la peor la opción 3. El problema con usar `eval` es que no es seguro y se puede usar para fines maliciosos.

**Cargando dinámicamente scripts**

Es tan simple como crear un elemento `script` y ponerle en el atributo `src` la dirección del script.

```
function loadScript (fileurl) {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = fileurl;
  document.body.append(script);
}
```

En el success de tu petición AJAX, solo debes insertar el script para ese documento:

```
success : function (data) {
  $(".1").html(data);
  loadScript('myscript.js');
}
```

**Evaluando scripts bajo demanda**

Ésta es la peor opción pero si no te importa mucho la seguridad quizás te sea útil.

```
let scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script')
for (let i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
    eval(scripts[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: ¿No sería otra opción, más simple, más segura y más práctica tener una sección que muestre la info del elemento seleccionado **en la misma página, sin tener que cargar de nuevo nada**?

Comment: ¿Por qué tendrías que recargar algo? Se supone por eso mismo usas AJAX, para obtener el template y **mostrarlo en la misma página**. La idea de esta pregunta es que si cada template tiene su propio script, entonces, mejor poner los scripts separados y cargarlos en cuanto se haga un fetch del template.

Comment: @gugadev podria usar mejor eventListeners en los botonoes

Answer (score 0):

Fijate que tenes un `<p>` con href, esta propiedad es para los `<a>`.
Si usas Jquery podes probar lo siguiente...

A los `<p>` deberias agregar una propiedad `data-url = "url-donde-ir.php"`.
Por ejemplo:
`<p class="s" data-url="aptoarriendo.php"><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>Apartamentos</p>`

y la funcion seria...

```
function cargarDoc(url) {
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    dataType: "text",
    success : function (data) {
        $(".1").html(data);
    }
});}
$(document).on("click",".s",function(){
     var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
     cargarDoc(url);
}
```